# Sorting computed fields of an association in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 2 tables Videos and Views. Videos has many Views. I am running this query:

```
$query = $this->Videos->find('all');
$query->select([
    'id',
    'title',
    'user_id',
    'purchase_count',
    'created',
    'price',
    'total_price'=>$query->newExpr()->add('price*purchase_count'),
    'created'
])->distinct();
$query->contain([
    'Views'=>function($v)use($from,$to){
         return $v->select([
            'id',
            'video_id',
            'free_views_total'=>$v->func()->sum('free_views'),
            'subscription_view_total'=>$v->func()->sum('subscription_view')
        ])
        ->where([
        'Views.created >='=>$from,'Views.created <='=>$to])->group('video_id');
}]);

$this->paginate=[
             'sortWhitelist' => [
                 'id',
                 'title',
                 'user_id',
                 'Views.free_views_total',
                 'Views.subscription_view_total',
                 'purchase_count',
                 'price',
                 'total_price',
                 'created'
             ]];
```

This query is working fine but I am not able to sort by `free_views_total` and `subscription_view_total`. I have also added these in `sortWhitelist`. But it is also not working. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of the hasMany relationship cake does not join the tables but rather performs many queries and join the resultsets.

there are many things you can do

You can search by Views

```
$this->Videos->Views->find()
->group(['video_id'])
->contain('Videos')
```

or you can use [leftJoinWith](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith) instead of contain

```
$query->leftJoinWith([Views'=>function($v)use($from,$to){ ...
```